# No aggregate frame stats of the Native Activity sample

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, rendering

I run the [Native Activity sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity/) on MI Pad 4 Plus, with Android version 8.1.0.  It's ok. Then, I run "adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo com.example.native_activity ". It shows a little bit of information, without aggregate frame stats nor HISTOGRAM. Attached please find the screenshot.
Is there any settings needed in the develop phase for this sample to get the gfxinfo?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqmGU.jpg)